# Why does adding a potential exception result in slower performance even if never thrown?

Tags: c++, performance, exception

I copied the code of Moro's Inverse Cumulative function of Normal distribution, where I added an extra error handling to deal with the input that is out of range (0,1). When I tested the code with all valid inputs, the speed is slowed down about 25% (6ns vs 8ns). I'm quite curious that why even no execution the throw exception still slow down the performance?

Code of Inverse function:

```
double Inverse(double u)
{
    double a[4] = {
        2.50662823884,
        -18.61500062529,
        41.39119773534,
        -25.44106049637 };

    double b[4] = {
        -8.47351093090,
        23.08336743743,
        -21.06224101826,
        3.13082909833   };
    double c[9] = {
        0.3374754822726147,
        0.9761690190917186,
        0.1607979714918209,
        0.0276438810333863,
        0.0038405729373609,
        0.0003951896511919,
        0.0000321767881768,
        0.0000002888167364,
        0.0000003960315187  };

    // Assert( 0 < u && u < 1 );  
    if (u >= 1 || u <= 0){
        throw std::invalid_argument("Input out of range.");
    }

    /*return the inverse of cumulative normal distribution fonction*/

    double x, r;

    x = u - 0.5;
    if (fabs(x)<0.42) {
        r = x*x;
        r = x*(((a[3] * r + a[2])*r + a[1])*r + a[0]) / ((((b[3] * r + b[2])*r + b[1])*r + b[0])*r + 1.0);
        return(r);
    }
    r = u;
    if (x>0.0) r = 1 - u;
    r = log(-log(r));
    r = c[0] + r*(c[1] + r*(c[2] + r*(c[3] + r*(c[4] + r*(c[5] + r*(c[6] + r*(c[7] + r*c[8])))))));
    if (x<0.0) r = -r;
    return(r);
}
```

And the test code is

```
int m = 1000000, n = 1000;
double z, p, dz = 1.0 / double(m) / double(n);
clock_t t1, t2;
t1 = clock();
z = 1e-9;
p = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        z += dz * 0.999;
        p = Inverse(z);
    }
}
t2 = clock();
cout << z << '\t' << p << endl;
cout << "Inverse" << '\t' << float(t2 - t1) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
```

Comment: You're doing an `if`.  That means your doing more instructions which means more work.

Comment: Are those two extra nanoseconds really worth the extra effort? The difference is at best just an environmental one.

Comment: This is why functions that have to be fast should not check their inputs, but document what the expected range is. Let the user ensure that they're not violating the function's requirements.

Comment: First this difference really exists and is very stable. Second it has nothing to do with the if statement because when I remove the throw but keeping the if, the extra time consumption disappears.

Comment: @PeteBecker But it only does a judgement and won't cost too much time, doesn't it?

Comment: @YangWang If you remove the throw and keep an empty if, the compiler has probably optimized it away and it's not present in generated code. See if the difference persists in an unoptimized version.

Comment: Or put some minuscule side effect inside the loop and keep the optimization enabled.

Comment: And your  compiling with -O2 or greater.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the exception is not executed, the computer still has to check the value of the variable 'u' in the condition, which takes time.